# React Bootstrap4 modal placement

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap4-modal

I've got a component that opens a bootstrap modal (using react-bootstrap4-modal)

It opens and closes using this

```
{this.state.inEditMode ? <MemberModal /> : null}
```

However, because the component is already nested somewhere in the DOM, it's not a valid placement for bootstrap modal markup. It leaves a nasty white bar at the bottom, which I confirmed does not happen if it's located within the outermost `<App/>` `div` tag.

Is there a simple way to fix this? Or will it require me putting all of my modal components within `<App/>` and changing the state of `<App/>` from within nested children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [z-index stacking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) issue and was a common problem until React introduced [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). Dan Abrimov from the FB team put together a code pen with an example that can be found [here](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/yzMaBd).

> Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node
>   that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component.
>
> A typical use case for portals is when a parent component has an
>   overflow: hidden or z-index style, but you need the child to visually
>   “break out” of its container. For example, **dialogs**, hovercards, and
>   tooltips.
>
> Normally, when you return an element from a component’s render method,
>   it’s mounted into the DOM as a child of the nearest parent node:

```
render() {
  // React mounts a new div and renders the children into it
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

> However, sometimes it’s useful to insert a child into a different
>   location in the DOM:

```
render() {
  // React does *not* create a new div. It renders the children into `domNode`.
  // `domNode` is any valid DOM node, regardless of its location in the DOM.
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    this.props.children,
    domNode
  );
}
```